# Is it Dart Server or the browser that performs Xsl transformations?

Tags: xml, xslt, dart, dart-polymer

Are xsl transformations performed by the dart server or is it any modern browser that performs it?

if I try to open and xml file containing a link to the .xsl file then Chrome won't open it at all whereas Firefox will. I've worked out that this is just a security issue. To actually view the xml file through xslt to turn it into an html file in Chrome I can run Pub Serve or just use a Python server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl" ?>
```

the xsl file contains html with w3 namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
```

Thus, I'm just wondering are there actual files in dart:io or dart:html that are performing this xslt or is it chrome that is performing the xslt?

In the bottom of the [dart:html](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.1/dart-html/dart-html-library.html) library there are bunch of deprecated class files relating to xml, xpath and one for [XsltProcessor](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.1/dart-html/XsltProcessor-class.html).

I'm glad the xslt transformations are working in polymer components so far and was wondering where the programming is coming from.

Comment: You can transform local XML files with local stylesheets if you run Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option.

Comment: You might like to look at Saxon-JS, which is a Javascript library for doing XSLT transformation in the browser. It's XML and XSLT support is much more up-to-date than the old XSLT 1.0 engines built in to the browsers.

Comment: nwellnhof; yeah, I knew it was a security concern. yet the location of Chrome is actually different depending upon the linux distros. I thought soe when I was able to view the file in mozilla but not in chrome unless I ran dart Pub Serve or python - SimpleHTTTServer 9000

Comment: Michael, I think you mean [Saxonica-CE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) which is fine. I'm just trying to figure out what level of support [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Transforming_XML_with_XSLT) has built in for xslt already. You think it's just xslt 1.0? There's support for CSS 1 + 2. I'd really like [Xslt 2.0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XSLT_2.0) and am wondering what support dart has like java's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is just because Chrome has tighter security constraints when files are loaded from a `file://` url then when loaded from an `http://` url.
`pub serve` doesn't do anything to xml files except serving.

AFAIK XML support in Chrome is deprecated. I assume this is why related methods are deprecated in `dart:html` as well.

Comment: hi zoeichi, i believe you're right. it is a security issue with files from the root file :// but, if you have time tomorrow, can you explain further 'deprecated.' That can mean a lot of things. A simple search of the flutter repo for 'xml' may indicate otherwise.....perhaps something about an 'AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: Sorry, it seems I mixed something up https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/zIg2KC7PyH0

Comment: Tks 4fur the link, zoeichi. Lots to read. Do you mind if I ask some questions later? Was xml completely dropped for json? Has dart not hit up against sgml?

Comment: I got the impression that XML was ditched from the browser but it seems it only was XSLT. Not sure what you mean by " Has dart not hit up against sgml?"

Comment: the blink-dev link was helpful and the issue from 2013 was [raised again](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/xslt/blink-dev/6MOMhQaX3N8/sK2BQp-_BQAJ) just a year ago. At least now I have a better understanding of where Chrome is regarding xml and xslt and 'deprecated.' [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) was the precursor of HTML and XML and so I just presumed, incorrectly , that dart would have come up against it as other languages have. tks, again.